# Graphical problem when viewing information about a Simulink block

Tags: 18.04, matlab, ubuntu-mate

I'm using MATLAB 2015a on Ubuntu MATE 18.04. I'm facing an issue on Simulink, the following image should suffice:

[image]

As you can see, the information about the blocks are displayed like this!.

I'm using OpenGL with MATLAB, no problem there I think...

Anyway to fix this?

Comment: Try to switch theme in `mate-appearance-properties`.

Comment: @N0rbert I'm using the default theme... I tried switching to other themes, but it didn't work!